# Rails app using Oauth to post to Twitter, getting "not authorized" when running in production server. OK in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to use Twitter's Oauth Single Token for posting from a rails app to my twitter feed (single user use-case is perfect for my app). [This](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token#ruby) Is what I'm talking about.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
twitter_consumer_key = 'AAAAAA...'
twitter_consumer_secret = 'BBBBBB///'
oauth_token = 'CCCCC....'
oauth_token_secret = 'DDD.....'

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(twitter_consumer_key, twitter_consumer_secret, :site => "http://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header)
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, :oauth_token => oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret => oauth_token_secret)
response = access_token.post("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json", {:status => "Coffee's ready at 191 Peachtree!! "+Time.now.to_i.to_s})
logger.info response.inspect
```

When I run this in my local machine, everything goes well and the post is created on my feed. When I run it on my production server (centos5.5, Apache 2, Passenger, Rails 3.0.4) I get "HTTPUnauthorized".

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any more content in the response body? For example, I forced an unauthorized error, and the response body contains `{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Incorrect signature"}`

Comment: Is your site enabled in the authorized callback url list of your Twitter app?

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the tip! My server's timezone was incorrectly set so I was getting the following error in the response body: {"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Timestamp out of bounds"}
I set the time and timezone correctly and now it's working fine. :)

Comment: add the solution as an answer and accept it incase other developers have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per abraham's comment, I'm adding the solution as an answer instead of a comment:

My server's timezone was incorrectly set so I was getting the following error in the response body:

```
{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Timestamp out of bounds"}
```

I set the time and timezone correctly and now it's working fine.

:)

Comment: Timezone was set to UTC instead of UTC-5, which is the correct time zone for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with filling Callback URL in settings of your application on dev.twitter.com.
Should be something like that:

Callback URL    *http://yousite.com/auth/twitter/callback*